# Cannot retrieve out parameters from oracle stored procedure using OracleManagedDataAccess

Tags: oracle, output

I m writing my issue here after lot of struggle and trying all the available options online.
Here is my issue. I am using ODP.Net, oracleManagedDataAccess library to connect to the oracle database.I have a stored procedure with in and out parameters  which works fine when I test it from pl/sql but when I am trying to execute it from my .net code and retrieve the out parameters they return null and if I see the status of each out parameter, its false and value is "Null Fetched" and also the size of the parameter is showing up as 0, though I set the size of the parameter to 4000 for a string type. Please see my code below. Please help. As I told you earlier, my stored proc works just fine from pl/sql.

connection = new OracleConnection(DBHelper.ConnectionString);
               connection.Open();

```
           command = new OracleCommand();
           command.Connection = connection;
           command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
           command.CommandText = DBConstants.PROC_GETBORROWERSEQNO;

           //Input
           command.Parameters.Add("password", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000, password, ParameterDirection.Input);
           command.Parameters.Add("userid", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000, userID, ParameterDirection.Input);
           command.Parameters.Add("ipaddress", OracleDbType.Varchar2,4000, iPAddress, ParameterDirection.Input);    


           //Output                                
           command.Parameters.Add("shawcustno", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           command.Parameters.Add("emailid", OracleDbType.Varchar2,4000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           command.Parameters.Add("contr_phase", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           command.Parameters.Add("source_seqno", OracleDbType.Decimal,15).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           command.Parameters.Add("borrower_seqno", OracleDbType.Decimal,15).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
           command.Parameters.Add("pag_phone", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;  

           command.Parameters.Add("pag", OracleDbType.Varchar2, 4000).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

           //InputOutput
           command.Parameters.Add("sessionseqno", OracleDbType.Decimal).Direction = ParameterDirection.InputOutput;

           sequenceNumber = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
           customer = new Customer();
           customer.Company = command.Parameters["company"].Value.ToString();
           customer.Pag = command.Parameters["pag"].GetString();
           customer.PagPhone = command.Parameters["pag_phone"].GetString();
           customer.BorrowerSeqNo = command.Parameters["borrower_seqno"].IsDBNull() ? 0 :    command.Parameters["borrower_seqno"].GetInt32();
           customer.SourceSeqNo = command.Parameters["source_seqno"].IsDBNull() ? 0 :    command.Parameters["source_seqno"].GetInt32(); 
           customer.EmailID = command.Parameters["emailid"].GetString();
           customer.ShawCustNo = command.Parameters["shawcustno"].GetString();
           customer.SessionSeqNo = command.Parameters["sessionseqno"].IsDBNull() ? 0 :    command.Parameters["sessionseqno"].GetInt32();                
       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally found the answer, the order of the arguments has to be exactly the same as that declared in the stored procedure. I missed that order.